# ScalaJS: how to parse ajax response from JSON to a case class

Tags: json, scala, scala.js, upickle, playscalajs

I'm trying ScalaJS with Play! Scala 2.4 and the serialization library for Scala uPickle.

I don't manage to parse the return of an AJAX call.

Here is my case class:

```
@JSExportAll
case class Room(id: String, name: String, presentation: String, images: Seq[String], isAnApartment: Boolean )
```

I have a controller on the server side returning a sequence of rooms:

```
 val rooms = Seq(room1, room2, room3)
 def findAll() = Action {
   Ok(write(rooms))
 }
```

(Rooms are some instance of the Room class.)

Now I want to deserialize these object on the client side. Here is the snippet of code which does not work:

```
Ajax.get("/rooms")
  .onSuccess { case response =>
     read[Seq[Room]](response.responseText)
  }
```

but I get this runtime exception:

```
RuntimeException: There were linking errors
```

What I want to do seems very easy but I don't manage to make it work, any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm.  Where are you getting that error from?  What are you doing when it's happening?  That's a JVM error as far as I know -- where are you seeing the error?  (Actually, it looks like that error sometimes happens when you try to use JVM-only code in Scala.js.  Do you have a repo with the full code?)

Comment: The "There were linking errors" should be accompanied by a "Trying to reach blablabla" and a sort-of-stack trace. Could you please paste them in your question? Without that it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Educated guess: did you make sure to use `%%%` in your dependency on uPickle, and not `%%`?

Comment: Ok thanks srjd ! The problem was indeed that I used %% instead of %%% in my depencies.